# AWS Elastic Beanstalk RDS_DB_NAME environment variable is ignored (Rails 5)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, environment-variables, amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been playing with the **ebdb** database that Elastic Beanstalk creates in RDS. It appears that the **RDS_DB_NAME** environment variable in the Elastic Beanstalk console can be left blank without affecting the functioning of the app:

[image]

I have restarted the App Server (using the EB console) with no effect. I note that when I go into RDS, the database name is still strangely listed as **ebdb**:

[image]

Can anyone confirm this behaviour, and - if I am correct - how might I swap to a different database on RDS? (In my case I am testing backup and restore and want to have my Rails 5.2 app point to the restored database temporarily.)

FWIW, I have the standard Rails config/database.yml:

```
production:
  <<: *default
  database: <%= ENV['RDS_DB_NAME'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['RDS_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['RDS_PASSWORD'] %>
  host: <%= ENV['RDS_HOSTNAME'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['RDS_PORT'] %>
```

Comment: If I assume that AWS does not cache the env data somehow, the only thing that comes to mind is that your app is not running in production env?

Comment: Thanks, @MladenIlić. Good idea, but I have checked that RACK_ENV is set to "production". Maybe that variable does nothing either!

Comment: Try setting `RAILS_ENV` to `production`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it is not possible to set the name of the DB. As Nezir suggests below, create a DB through EB only for testing purposes. For production purposes, use AWS RDS directly to create a DB. Store the metadata of your AWS RDS then as environment variables in Elastic Beanstalk.

Comment: use double quotes, e.g.: <%= ENV["RDS_DB_NAME"] %>

Answer (score 1):

From user experience he is suggesting in his [blog](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/10/26/do-not-associate-rds-instance-with-beanstalk-environment/) this:

**Do not associate RDS instance with Beanstalk environment**
Elastic Beanstalk allows you to associate a RDS instance when you create a new environment. However, I recommend you NOT to do so in production.

First, here are some pros of doing it:

Elastic Beanstalk automatically creates the RDS instance, as well as the properly configured security group.
Environment variables are injected into all your EC2 instances (like RDS_HOSTNAME, RDS_USERNAME…).
However, there is a big con that, to me, make it unusable in production: now, the RDS is associated with your environment. This means that if for whatever reason you need to rebuild the environment (for instance to update the Elastic Beanstalk AMI), you’re stuck because Elastic Beanstalk will delete any associated resource (like your RDS instance). You then need to create a snapshot of the RDS instance, and recreate a new one from it. This will lead to some downtime.

The best way, to my opinion, is to create the RDS instance separately, and manually inject the RDS environment variables into the newly created environment, using the Elastic Beanstalk GUI tool, for instance. This is much more flexible!

**Please go to the blog link and read more about experiences in comment below a [blog post](http://www.michaelgallego.fr/blog/2013/10/26/do-not-associate-rds-instance-with-beanstalk-environment/).**

Comment: Thanks, @Nezir. Yes I read that blog too yesterday and have concluded that EB is not as robust as I’d hoped for a product that’s 5+ (?) years old.

Comment: you can prevent deletion of RDS database by going to it's setting in RDS dashboard and protecting it from deletion. I see no reason for creating it manually

Comment: Good response, I've had similar experiences with EB-RDS in the past. However it appears that this is no longer a hurdle as you can disassociate the RDS and use/modify it normally outside of Elastic Beanstalk.